# Consolidate XML data using SQL query

Tags: sql, xml

I am fairly new to XML and I have been asked to create a data file in XML format using SQL.  I need to query multiple tables in the database to get all the necessary information and need to consolidate the information in the XML output. I am struggling with how to consolidate the data in the expected format. Any and all suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!             This is the query I am testing with-

```
(select
    p.acctno as [Demographic/PatientID],
    p.patdob as [Demographic/DOB],
    c.poscode as [Procedure/Facility],
        (select
            CAST(c.acctno as varchar(10)) +
                 CONVERT(varchar(10), c.dateofservice, 112) as [AnesthesiaRecordID],
            (select
                d.provcode as [AnesthesiaStaff/ProvCode]
            FOR XML PATH ('AnesthesiaStaffSet'), TYPE
            )
        FOR XML PATH ('AnethesiaCase'), TYPE
        )
    from patdemo_t p
        inner join charge_t c on p.acctno = c.acctno
        inner join provcode_t d on c.provcode = d.provcode
    where
        p.acctno in (12345, 54321) 
        and c.dateofservice in ('2018-02-15','2018-02-01')
    group by p.acctno, c.poscode, p.patdob, p.patfname,
             p.patlname, c.acctno, c.dateofservice, d.provcode
)
FOR XML PATH ('AnesthesiaRecord'), ROOT('AnesthesiaRecords'), TYPE
```

My output is like this-

```
<AnesthesiaRecords>
  <AnesthesiaRecord>
    <Demographic>
      <PatientID>12345</PatientID>
      <DOB>1972-03-30T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Demographic>
    <Procedure>
      <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
    </Procedure>
    <AnethesiaCase>
      <AnesthesiaRecordID>1234520180201</AnesthesiaRecordID>
      <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
        <AnesthesiaStaff>
          <ProvCode>BUS</ProvCode>
        </AnesthesiaStaff>
      </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
    </AnethesiaCase>
  </AnesthesiaRecord>
  <AnesthesiaRecord>
    <Demographic>
      <PatientID>12345</PatientID>
      <DOB>1972-03-30T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Demographic>
    <Procedure>
      <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
    </Procedure>
    <AnethesiaCase>
      <AnesthesiaRecordID>1234520180201</AnesthesiaRecordID>
      <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
        <AnesthesiaStaff>
          <ProvCode>OBR</ProvCode>
        </AnesthesiaStaff>
      </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
    </AnethesiaCase>
  </AnesthesiaRecord>
  <AnesthesiaRecord>
    <Demographic>
      <PatientID>54321</PatientID>
      <DOB>2006-04-01T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Demographic>
    <Procedure>
      <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
    </Procedure>
    <AnethesiaCase>
      <AnesthesiaRecordID>5432120180215</AnesthesiaRecordID>
      <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
        <AnesthesiaStaff>
          <ProvCode>LUN</ProvCode>
        </AnesthesiaStaff>
      </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
    </AnethesiaCase>
  </AnesthesiaRecord>
  <AnesthesiaRecord>
    <Demographic>
      <PatientID>54321</PatientID>
      <DOB>2006-04-01T00:00:00</DOB>
    </Demographic>
    <Procedure>
      <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
    </Procedure>
    <AnethesiaCase>
      <AnesthesiaRecordID>5432120180215</AnesthesiaRecordID>
      <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
        <AnesthesiaStaff>
          <ProvCode>REA</ProvCode>
        </AnesthesiaStaff>
      </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
    </AnethesiaCase>
  </AnesthesiaRecord>
</AnesthesiaRecords>
```

The output needs to be consolidated like this-

```
<AnesthesiaRecords>
      <AnesthesiaRecord>
        <Demographic>
          <PatientID>12345</PatientID>
          <DOB>1972-03-30T00:00:00</DOB>
        </Demographic>
        <Procedure>
          <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
        </Procedure>
        <AnethesiaCase>
          <AnesthesiaRecordID>1234520180201</AnesthesiaRecordID>
          <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
            <AnesthesiaStaff>
              <ProvCode>BUS</ProvCode>
            </AnesthesiaStaff>
            <AnesthesiaStaff>
              <ProvCode>OBR</ProvCode>
            </AnesthesiaStaff>
          </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
        </AnethesiaCase>
      </AnesthesiaRecord>
     <AnesthesiaRecord>
        <Demographic>
          <PatientID>54321</PatientID>
          <DOB>2006-04-01T00:00:00</DOB>
        </Demographic>
        <Procedure>
          <Facility>LHOP </Facility>
        </Procedure>
        <AnethesiaCase>
          <AnesthesiaRecordID>5432120180215</AnesthesiaRecordID>
          <AnesthesiaStaffSet>
          <AnesthesiaStaff>
              <ProvCode>LUN</ProvCode>
            </AnesthesiaStaff>
            <AnesthesiaStaff>
              <ProvCode>REA</ProvCode>
            </AnesthesiaStaff>
          </AnesthesiaStaffSet>
      </AnethesiaCase>
      </AnesthesiaRecord>
    </AnesthesiaRecords>
```

Comment: Please shrink this to the relevant parts and work out the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you ask a question please add some sample data, best with DDL and DML ([read about MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). And try to reduce youe part to the relevant pieces. If there might be more than one: 2 is enough. If there are several *of the same*: 1 is enough.

Your XML seems to be quite straight. Just one single row, some elements deeper nested, but still `1:1`. The only `1:n` element seems to be the `<AnesthesiaStaff>`. Your own query is pretty close actually.

What I changed:

- took away the `INNER JOIN provcode_t` and placed this within the sub-select (*correlated sub-query*).
- Changed `2018-02-05` to `20180205` as the ISO8601 format is not culture independant with `DATETIME` (don't now your target data type though)
- Placed the `AnesthesiaStaffSet` as `ROOT` for the sub-select and used `[*]` as the *column name* for the created inner XML

Try it out (I cannot test it)

```
select
p.acctno as [Demographic/PatientID],
p.patdob as [Demographic/DOB],
c.poscode as [Procedure/Facility],
    (select
        CAST(c.acctno as varchar(10)) +
             CONVERT(varchar(10), c.dateofservice, 112) as [AnesthesiaRecordID],
        (select
            d.provcode as [AnesthesiaStaff]
         from provcode_t d 
         where c.provcode = d.provcode
         FOR XML PATH ('AnesthesiaStaff'),ROOT('AnesthesiaStaffSet'), TYPE
        )
    FOR XML PATH ('AnethesiaCase'), TYPE
    ) AS [*]
from patdemo_t p
    inner join charge_t c on p.acctno = c.acctno
where
    p.acctno in (12345, 54321) 
    and c.dateofservice in ('20180215','20180201')
group by p.acctno, c.poscode, p.patdob, p.patfname,
         p.patlname, c.acctno, c.dateofservice
FOR XML PATH ('AnesthesiaRecord'), ROOT('AnesthesiaRecords'), TYPE
```

If this does not solve your issue, please use the edit option to add an MCVE to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback Shnugo!  I apologize for my lengthy question.  This is my first question on stack, so I will get better.  I tested your query and initially got an error that c.provcode needed to be in aggregate function or GROUP BY, so I added to the GROUP BY and got the same results.  I have tried this and it seems to be working!  Now I will try incorporating this with the other SQL.  Thank you for this valuable nugget of info!

Comment: @A.Durant ahh, yes... You had **d.** provcode, but removing this was wrong. You needed **c.** provcode. Happy Coding